# Is McDonalds (1999) omega a measure of unidimensionality or homogeneity?

Tags: heteroscedasticity

I recently read a paper in which the authors used Cronbach's $\alpha$ and $\omega$ as measures for unidimensionality and homogeneity. In case of $\alpha$ I know that it is wrong, but I am not so familiar with $\omega$. The literatur I read said it is the proportion of test variance due to a general factor. Does that mean a high value in $\omega$ would imply unidimensionality and homogeneity, because it seems some researchers seem to make a point to differentiate between $\omega$ and unidimensionality and homogeneity, but I do not see why.

Answer (score 0):

Both omega and alpha consider dimensionality, which is characteristic of correlations between variables.
The term 'homogeneity' is more appropriate in characterizing a similarity of individuals, not variables.